# Cómo corregir el error "1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" con procedure o procedimientos almacenados

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando hacer un procedure o procedimientos almacenado de inserción en la tabla **cliente** que esta referenciando a la tabla **usuarios** con el campo **idusuario**, al momento de hacer el llamado me sale el error, ¿como podría solucionarlo?

este es el codigo

```
create table usuarios(
idusuario int primary key auto_increment,
correo_usuario varchar(50) not null,
password_usuario varchar(20) not null,
estado_usuario varchar(20) not null,
idrol int,
foreign key (idrol) references rol (idrol)
);


    create table cliente(
idcliente int primary key auto_increment,
num_doc_cliente varchar(15) not null,
tipo_doc_cliente varchar(20) not null,
nombre_cliente varchar(50) not null,
apellido_cliente varchar(50) not null,
direccion_cliente varchar(50) not null,
telefono_cliente varchar(20) not null,
estado_cliente varchar(20) not null,
idusuario int,
foreign key (idusuario) references usuarios (idusuario)
);



delimiter //
create procedure insertar_cliente (in kidcliente int, knum_cod_cliente varchar(15), ktipo_doc_cliente varchar(20), knombre_cliente varchar(50), kapellido_cliente varchar(50),kdireccion_cliente varchar(50),ktelefono_cliente varchar(20),kestado_cliente varchar(20),kidusuario int )
begin
insert into cliente (idcliente,num_doc_cliente,tipo_doc_cliente,nombre_cliente,apellido_cliente,direccion_cliente,telefono_cliente,estado_cliente,idusuario) values (kidcliente,knum_cod_cliente,ktipo_doc_cliente,knombre_cliente,kapellido_cliente,kdireccion_cliente,ktelefono_cliente,kestado_cliente,kidusuario);
  end //
  delimiter ;

call insertar_cliente ('26','7698306892','CC','Mauricio','Trujillo','cra 109b #153-60, Bogotá, Colombia','3136048243','activo',51);
```

Comment: eliminas el id tanto del llamado `in kidcliente int` como del insert... es decir debr quedarte asi `insert into cliente (num_doc_cliente, num_doc_cliente....` y luego en call no pasarselo

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, me imagino que te referías al id usuario, ya me sirvió